# I want to read an entire MySQL table into ruby as an array. I am using active record

Tags: mysql, ruby, activerecord

I want to read an entire MySQL table (or table column) into ruby as an array. I am using active record, ruby 1.9, rails 3 and mysql 5.5.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want raw data then you can use [`connection.select_rows`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/DatabaseStatements.html#method-i-select_rows) inside one of your model classes (i.e. anything that inherits from ActiveRecord::Base):

```
a = []
connection.select_rows(%Q{
    select website
    from websites
}).each do |row|
    # row has the data (as an array of strings) for one row of results
    a.push(row[0])
end
# a now has your column values
```

There are other low level raw SQL methods listed in the doc I linked to above. You'll also want to know about the [quoting methods](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/Quoting.html) if you're doing stuff like this as there is no support for placeholders at this level.

Comment: How could this be changed to select a column called website, from a table called websites, from a database called data? I get it, I just don't really understand how the syntax works from you're link and answer. also what is the array called after this method? Thanks

Comment: @Benjamin: Do you have a Rails app set up? Any experience with Rails at all? Or are you starting from nothing and trying to access an existing database?

Comment: I am starting from scratch pretty much with little experience. have created the database myself. using active record.

Comment: @Benjamin: I'd recommend that you run through a few tutorial apps to get familiar with the terminology and the way Rails works before you get into anything "real".

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your model name is Model, you can do

```
Model.all
```

Comment: Can you expand this answer a bit please? I don't know what a model is. What if I wanted to read a column called "column1" from a table called "table1" thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To access a list of all of a 'User' model, you could do:

```
User.all
```

To access the name column of a specific user model, you could do:

```
my_user = User.first
my_user.name
```

I highly recommend taking a look at [Rails for Zombies](http://railsforzombies.org/). This will give you a great start! Good luck!